# How can I determine whether PC1 or PC2 is more effective to separate enzymes and non enzymes for the CD proteins?

Tags: pca, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

[image: The blue dots represents enzymes and red dots represent non-enzymes]

The score plot from the PCA is represented in the diagram. I performed the Mann Whitney U test for the Scores values for enzymes( blue dot in score plot) and non-enzymes ( red dot) for both PC1 and PC2. I found out that for both Pc1 and PC2, the enzymes and non-enzymes values were significant( both had p-value 0.00). Is there and way to find out by mann whitney U test ( by considering U value or any other values, whether PC1 or PC2 is more effective to seperate enzymes or non-enzymes?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there and way to find out by mann whitney U test ( by considering U value or any other values, whether PC1 or PC2 is more effective to seperate enzymes or non-enzymes?

### Yes.

I don't know if this is really what you ought to do, but to answer your question, recall that the U-statistic is related to the AUC (Area Under the Receiver Operator Characteristic), which is a metric of binary "separation" over a continuous score. See here: [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Area-under-curve_.28AUC.29_statistic_for_ROC_curves).

$$AUC={U\over n_1\cdot n_2}$$

The higher the AUC, the bigger the separability of labels in the given continuous score.